# why is id([1][::-1]) ==id([1]) returning True while [1][::-1] is [1] returning False?

Tags: python

I know the `is` operator compares the `id` of the two, not the value
but why is `id([1][::-1])==id([1])` returning `True` while `[1][::-1] is [1]` is returning `False`?

```
id([1][::-1]) ==id([1]) #True
[1][::-1] is [1] #Fasle

id([1]) ==id([1][::-1])#Fasle
[1] is [1][::-1]#False
```

Comment: don't use `is` here. Use `==`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is

Comment: I just want to know why [1][::-1]==[1] and id([1][::-1]) ==id([1])  is returning True while [1][::-1] is [1] is still returning False?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [Is there a difference between “==” and “is”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/132988/364696); this question is very specifically asking about why the `id`s appear to be the same, but the identity test doesn't agree.

Comment: What are the contents of `id`?

Comment: @Yatin: `id` is a built-in function, you can read the docs for details; on CPython, it returns the memory address of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id([1][::-1]) ==id([1])` being `True` is a quirk of CPython using a free list for `list`s being implemented as a stack. The first `id([1][::-1])` is completely evaluated, and the `list` it produced is freed by the time it finishes. When `[1]` allocates space for the new `list`, it's given the same memory at the same address, which (in CPython) is equivalent to its `id`.

`id`s are only guaranteed to be unique for as long as the object exists; since the original `list` is gone before you make the new `list`, no guarantees are violated by both of them having the same `id`s at slightly different points in time.

The order of the test matters because `id` itself is pulling from the set of recently freed blocks in the small object allocator. The ordering here is:

1. Original `[1]` is allocated at address A
2. Result of `[::-1]` is allocated at address B
3. Immediately thereafter, `[1]` allocation A is returned to `list`'s free list
4. `id` returns an `int` describing address B
5. Result of `[::-1]`, B, is returned to free list (ahead of A)
6. Second `[1]` is allocated, getting B, the memory previously used by `[::-1]`
7. `id` is called, accurately producing the same `id` as before (because the new `[1]` was given the memory recently freed from the `list` `[::-1]` produced), because both `list`s were using address B

That's actually more complicated than it needs to be; `id([1]) == id([1])` would end up with the same result as well (it would just leave one fewer `list`s on the `list` free list).

When you do it the other way around, this happens:

1. `[1]` is allocated at address A
2. `id` returns a new `int` describing address A
3. `[1]` is freed and address A is returned to the pool
4. The next `[1]` is allocated, getting A, the same memory as the first `[1]`
5. `[::-1]` is applied to it, getting a new `list` from fresh memory B; `[1]` is then thrown away
6. `id` is called on the result of `[::-1]` getting an `int` describing address B; the `id`s for addresses A and B don't match

If you created and stored both `list`s, then compared the `id`s of the still existing `list`s to one another, they would be unique because these memory reuse shenanigans wouldn't be able to occur.